# simple script executes, but console warns ~= 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter is not of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

This removes fixed menu bars at top of web pages (like SO has) when run in chrome's console. There are several other questions like this, but they ask "why doesn't this execute" (syntax errors?) - this is a simple and easily tested example, which executes but warns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

```
    var target = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(ii in target){
        if(window.getComputedStyle(target[ii]).position === 'fixed'){
           target[ii].style.display = 'none';
           console.log('it"s gone');
        }
    }
```

getElementsByTagName returns a live node list, how are they not considered elements?

Comment: try `for(ii of target){ 
        if(window.getComputedStyle(ii)` etc, or understand everything `for (ii in` iterates through :p

Comment: btw, why do so many pro sites block the page that way? SO's menu bar isn't bad, but some are. Between those and the EU mandated cookie warning it starts to seem crowded. That warning worries people about security, w/o mention that the server can keep info on THEIR  side, and also fosters the habit of clicking on things w/o reading them.

Comment: thx, Jaromanda X - didn't work:  for(ii of target) = no change,  if(window.getComputedStyle(ii) got me a different error & also quit working.

Comment: you're using some microsoft browser? did you also change `ii.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: I tried changing my log to console.log(ii, ii.toString), got: 45 ƒ toString() { [native code] }    . How might I view the live node list?

Comment: if `ii` is `45` in the console.log, then you are not using `for ... of`

Comment: Jaromanda X - fixed it! - changing to ii.style.display = 'none'; with your other changes got rid of the warning and it still works! And my console.log is now giving useful info, too.  I'm puzzled over why - just browser weirdness? I'm using chrome on lubuntu.

Comment: no, not browser weirdness, it's called using the code correctly ... i.e `changing to ii.style.display = 'none';` I told you to do that 23 minutes ago :p

Comment: been trying permutations - only the for_of, COMBINED WITH Jaromanda's other 2 changes referring to 'ii', rather than target[ii]  works. ? for_in ' loops only iterates over enumerable',  ? for_of "creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables."

Comment: Have you checked the answer I posted that has 3 different solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `for .. in` will get you more than just the indexes to that array like object (it's not an array, its a `HTMLCollection` I think or `NodeList`

solution 1: check if target.hasownPropert(ii) is true

```
var target = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var ii in target){
    if(target.hasOwnProperty(ii)) {
        if(window.getComputedStyle(target[ii]).position === 'fixed'){
           target[ii].style.display = 'none';
           console.log('it"s gone');
        }
    }
}
```

solution 2: use for ... of

```
var target = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var ii of target){
    if(window.getComputedStyle(ii).position === 'fixed'){
       ii.style.display = 'none';
       console.log('it"s gone');
    }
}
```

solution 3: use document.querySelectorAll

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(ii => {
    if(window.getComputedStyle(ii).position === 'fixed'){
       ii.style.display = 'none';
       console.log('it"s gone');
    }
});
```

Comment: Tested all 3, they work and   console.log(ii , ii.toString); gives sensible output, too. I had thought querySelectorAll didn't return a LIVE node list, and couldn't be used for changing properties -apparently not. A couple links that might help me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in">mdn for...in & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...inmdn for...of. I'd better read more about querySelectorAll, too. THANKS, it's been very educational.

Comment: not sure how `console.log(ii.toString)` (i.e. the function definition) is important to you

Comment: I saw your comment "not browser weirdness", and have been trying the original version changing just the for...in to for...of . I had thought I was just being more specific by using 'target[ii], but apparently for...of makes ii into something different  -  a node list node? I'm seeing what you mean about "use the code correctly". The weird part seems like the fact that the original version worked, but warned.

Comment: the original version worked ... but failed when it hit the other "properties" of a HTMLcollection - by then, all the actual nodes had been processed.

Comment: using console.log(ii, ii.toString) with your solutions is giving me the html node folllowed by the function definition. I just tried it without the , ii.toString part - with the original version logging ii just gave me the #, so I added the toString hoping for a clue. You're right, the ii.toString part is not useful.

Comment: `ii.toString()` MAY be more useful, but `ii.toString` is not